# Can I install Django Rest Framework in an uploaded website in pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, content-management-system, pythonanywhere

Summary:

1. I decided to use python for my thesis
2. I started my project while simultaneously studying about python and django
3. I've added a lot of contents, models, and apps in my project, and I just now realized that I need to create a Content Management System, and somebody told me to use Django Rest Framework.
4. I started searching on how to use it, and everything that I saw installed it before creating the project, and it might be too late for me because I might have a lot of errors that I might not be able to trace.(or maybe django rest framework should really be installed before starting)
5. Can someone tell me if its possible to just install it? Or a hint/tip for alternatives? I only have less than 2 weeks left before my defense. Thank you for the help and understanding, Im new sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can still install it mid project. Just make sure to add it to your 'INSTALLED_APPS' list in your project settings file.

```
// settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
]
```